# How can I convert integer to time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, time-format

```
Select EmployeeName,Length
From Callers
```

Results:

```
John Doe  94559
John Doe  100720
```

This is basically in military time, so I believe that this data translates to 9:45 AM EST and 10:07 AM EST. When I add (Select dbo.convertIntToTime(Length)*100) I'm able to get it into regular time format. When I try (Select EmployeeName,AVG(Length) I get the average but in integers and I'm not sure how to convert it to time format.

```
Select EmployeeName,AVG(Length)
From Callers
Group By EmployeeName
```

Results:

```
John Doe 106546
Tom Cruise 116275
Lebron James 156971
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That's a very, very odd way to store the time.  Is that really stored as an integer?  If you're going to do math on it, you'll need to convert it to "minutes since midnight", which is basically `CAST(FirstTime/10000 AS int)*3600 + (CAST(FirstTime/100 AS int) % 100) * 60 + FirstTime % 60`.

Comment: This is why choosing datatypes is so important. This should be stored using the time datatype instead of an int that causes all sorts of silliness.

Answer (score 0):

Those are not military time numbers. There is no 1569 in military or anytime for that matter. Military is 0000-2300 where 0000 would be 12:00AM and 2300 would be 11:00PM.

So 156971, if it was military time would be 3:69 PM and 71 seconds. Not possible.

Are you sure the time is being stored that way you think?

I would suggest changing the way it’s stored to a time stamp, would make it much easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Converting Integer to time SQL Server

Create Below function in Sql Server -

```
create function change_int_to_time
(
    @input int
)
returns time(2)
as
begin
       return dateadd(hour, (@input / 1000000) % 100,
              dateadd(minute, (@input / 10000) % 100,
              dateadd(second, (@input / 100) % 100, cast('00:00:00' as time(2)))))
end
```

Now Use this function wherever you want like in you case you can use it like below -

Example 1 :

```
Select EmployeeName,dbo.change_int_to_time(AVG(Length))
From Callers
Group By EmployeeName
```

Example 2 :

```
Select EmployeeName,dbo.change_int_to_time(Length)
From Callers
Group By EmployeeName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *TimeFromParts*:

```sql
Select 
    EmployeeName, 
    Length,
    TimeFromParts(Length/ 10000, Length / 100 % 100, Length % 100, 0, 0) As TrueTime
From 
    Callers
```

To average, convert first to DateTime, then *Float*, average this, and convert back to *time*:

```sql
Select 
    EmployeeName, 
    Convert(Time(0), Convert(DateTime, Avg(Convert(Float, Convert(DateTime, TimeFromParts(Length / 10000, Length / 100 % 100, Length % 100, 0, 0)))))) As AverageLength
From 
    Callers
Group By
    EmployeeName
```

Comment: Yes, but it is an expression, not a function, which may be more convenient. The conversion is the crucial part. Use `Avg` to obtain the average value, nothing special.

Comment: Yes, it turns out to be more convoluted. See extended answer, please.

Comment: It is pure math only. It splits your concatenated hour-minute-second value, say, 100720 into 10,  7, and 20 which are used as the first three arguments for `TimeFromParts`.